# change format of bison error messages?

Tags: bison

Is there any way to change the format of Bison error messages? For example, instead of saying `syntax error, unexpected T_ID, expected ';' or T_IMPORT` saying `unexpected id, expected a semicolon or import`—doubly so with things like `$end`.

I know at worst I can do string operations to fix the string, but that seems a bit ridiculous.

Comment: An easy fix is to give meaningful names to the tokens. You might want to define `';'` in your tokeniser as T_SEMICOLON, something like that. You could also write a "prettify" function, that converts the token name to lower case and gets rid of `T_`.

Comment: Duplicate of [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27943284/how-to-get-more-parse-error-information-from-lex-yacc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27943284/how-to-get-more-parse-error-information-from-lex-yacc)

Answer (score 3):

In order to get something better than

```
syntax error, unexpected T_ID
```

instead of

```
%token T_ID
```

do

```
%token T_ID "identifier"
```

and the message will be

```
syntax error, unexpected identifier
```

In the particular case of `$end`, do this:

```
%token T_EOF 0 "end of file"
```

If you need internationalization support, use `_(...)`:

```
%token T_ID _("identifier")
%token T_EOF 0 _("end of file")
```

Since Bison 3.6 you can go further and generate the error message yourself.  The parser will give you the list of expected tokens, and the unexpected one, you'll be in charge of forging the message handed to `yyerror`.  See [The Syntax Error Reporting Function `yyreport_syntax_error`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_node/Syntax-Error-Reporting-Function.html) in the documentation for more details.