# How to get more parse error information from lex / yacc?

Tags: c++, c, yacc, lex

How to get more parse error information from lex / yacc?

Currently in the lex file I am using:

```
int yyerror(const char *msg)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Parse error: %s\n", msg);
    return 0;
}
```

But when I run my program yyerror outputs a blank message.  I tried adding yylineno and yytext to yyerror but these cause compilation errors.  I tried adding "%error-verbose" to the yacc file and 
"%option debug" to the lex file but these made no difference to the message.

I did notice however that yyparse outputs a bracket: '{' from the file I am trying to parse, I don't know the significance of this.

I am using win_flex and win_bison.

Comment: Here's maybe some more helpful information for you [**error handling in YACC**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9796608/error-handling-in-yacc)

Comment: Did you declare yyerror in your bison file? Do you compile with `-Wall` so that you are warned about missing prototypes? Do you specify `%option nodefault` in your flex file so that you are warned about input which matches no pattern?

Answer (score 0):

Much of this is described in the [official bison manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_node/Error-Reporting.html#Error-Reporting) when it shows how to use `yyerror` to get improved error messages.

In particular, it suggests you use `%define parse.error verbose` in the Bison declarations section to get enhanced error messages.